# Importing PHP string with quotes

Tags: php, expressionengine

So I'm importing ExpressionEngine fields into a php array. I want to display one field, called {gearboxx_body}, unless that field has more then 300 characters, in which case I want to display a field called {article_blurb}. I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to do this just in ExpressionEngine fields and conditionals, so I tried some PHP, which I'm just starting to learn:

```
<?php 

  $info = array('{gearboxx_body}','{article_blurb}');

  if(mb_strlen($info[0]) <= 300) 
    echo($info[0]);
  }

  else {
   echo($info[1]);
  }

?>
```

So that works well, but there's a problem. If the tag includes any apostrophes or quote marks, it ends the string and the page won't load. So what can I do about this? I've tried to replace the quote marks in the string, but I have to have loaded the string from the fields first, and as soon as I do that the page is already broken.

Hopefully that made sense. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure I follow. What is the `tag` you're talking about? I assume the `string` is `$info[0]`? Sounds like you've already tried http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you handle this in an EE plugin rather than in the template:

- Faster to render (because you don't need the overhead of PHP in the templates)
- More secure and reliable
- Faster to develop once you get the basics of EE development down <sup>which is a useful life skill</sup>
- All around best-practice

The plugin I have in mind takes three parameters:

body, blurb and character limit.

Let's say you call your plugin "Blurby".  In the template you would just have this:

```
{exp:blurby body="{gearboxx_body}" blurb="{article_blurb}" char_limit="300"}
```

It variably returns either of your fields based on the logic you define in the plugin itself.

See [plugin developer documentation](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/plugins.html).

---

Alternatively you could use the dreaded [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax to set variables before passing them into your array:

```
$body = <<<EOT
{gearboxx_body}
EOT;

$blurb = <<<EOT
{article_blurb}
EOT;
```

Comment: Let's say I'm not programmer savvy enough to create a plugin. I might be able to figure it out, but this is just a very small area of a fairly small project. Can you recommend just a small, simple way to prevent the page from breaking if there's any quotes in the fields?

Comment: Perhaps you want PHP's `addslashes()` function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: I think HEREDOC is your answer.  Updated above.

Comment: EE's parse order will be a problem here, and is the problem the OP is running into. One solution is to use a plugin tag pair - such as {exp:blurby length="300"}{my-field}{/exp:blurby}. Then have the plugin return true/false based on the length parameter. As per http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/25826/check-field-length

Comment: Just as a side point, I coincidentally ran into the same problem today on another place. This time it's not comparing the lengths of two fields, it's just putting a field into an html attribute, and the quotes mess it up. The HEREDOC doesn't work this time because as long as the output has any time of quotes in it, the attribute ends at the quote. It isn't crashing the page like this one was, just really annoying

Comment: Glad that helped. Feel free to ask another question... in a separate question. :-)